# Why do libgit2 methods using kernel32.dll's GetProcAddress always return 0?

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

I have the need to manually handle the loading / unloading of the actual `git2.dll`, instead of using `[DllImport("git2")]` in C#. I seem to have issues with creating an `IntPtr` for reference to the address of methods stored in `libgit2`.

Here're the good bits from my `PluginManager` class which are supposed to help facilitate manually loading, marshal/delegate (whenever I get this kink fixed), and unloading libraries.

```cs
public class PluginManager {
    public const string LIB = "Assets\\Plugins\\git2.dll";

    [DllImport( "kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi )]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary( [In, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStr )] string lib );

    [DllImport( "kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true )]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress( [In] IntPtr reference, [In, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStr )] string method );

    [DllImport( "kernel32.dll" )]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary( [In] IntPtr reference );
}
```

Here's where I attempt to use them:

```cs
//# Working; always non-zero.
IntPtr reference = PluginManager.LoadLibrary( PluginManager.LIB );

//# Should be valid -- LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.cs calls this method, too.
//# Always returns IntPtr.Zero.
IntPtr methodReference = PluginManager.GetProcAddress( reference, "git_repository_open" );
```

Is the library not exposed to this type of loading? I've tried all kinds of methods present in the `LibGit2Sharp` native hooks, but they always return zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `git2.dll` has mangled export names, so `git_repository_open` is actually `_git_repository_open@4`. After researching some more on why this is happening, it seems that, according to [This Post](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?462088-RESOLVED-GetProcAddress-failed&s=96531aaaf034ab631449495d3ca82242&p=1765423#post1765423), and several others that I've run into while looking for a fix, that the functions may not be exported using `extern "C"` or may not be using a `.def` file.

I did look through some of the `libgit2` code, and I saw `extern` used on a couple functions, but on others I saw no export keyword at all, but they're still being accessed externally from `LigGit2Sharp`'s `NativeMethods.cs` class.

While all of that is foreign to me, I did find a very useful post about a tool shipped with `Visual Studio` that allows you to see all exported items, and their names: [Dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30e78zd0.aspx). With this, I was able to determine the exported names, and used the `/OUT:filename` flag to save them to a file: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/q1g72rSu)

With all of the exported names at my disposal, I just have to follow function calls, that I'm actually using, and replace the the methods in `NativeMethods.cs` to look something like this: [LibGit2Sharp Issue #341](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/341).

Comment: If you need your dll to be built with `cdecl` instead of `stdcall`, you should build it that way.